# SVG saving so less C data

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, save, cc-2014

I'm saving some SVG icons from Illustrator CC 2014 and when I give them to my dev he says can you make less CDATA.
Does anyone know how?

Thanks

Comment: Smaller files.. less objects.

Comment: Voted to close because I don't know what file size has to do with design.

Comment: @Ryan the whole process of digital 'design' revolves around file sizes and such.

Comment: @chrishampshire that doesn't mean your question has anything to do with design. You should ask this question on http://www.superuser.com instead.

Comment: @chrishampshire you're welcome. Good luck finding out over there.

Comment: We already have a similar question to this.  Click on the link at the top and review the question and answers

Comment: I have also found auseful link incase anyone stumbles to my question in the future. http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2013/09/exporting-svg-illustrator.html